# How to Terminate PINTool after specified amount of time

Tags: intel-pin

My requirement is to run Intel PIN tool for specified amount of time lets say around 1 minute and then terminate.
For example:
I want to run notepad.exe for 1 minute under PIN. After 1 minute do post processing and close the log files properly and terminate notepad.exe using PINTool.

Answer (score 2):

Use `PIN_ExitApplication()` to achieve this. You can perform post processing in the Fini callback.

Comment: Great! If it works, consider accepting and up voting the answer :)